# Error Log programmatically chat using Parse.com

Tags: chat, tableview, parse-platform

Hello everyone I'm inserting a chat in my app through the tutorial
http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com

P.s. Beautiful Tutorial!

Well, I've already changed all deprecated and solved the problem of the double call in the query **- (void) loadLocalChat**, in the tutorial was still displayed a query that was used with the old SDK Parse.

Currently everything works but when I go to send a message, while saving the Log gives me the following error and the app crashes.

> exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (1) differs from count of
>   keys (3)'

And 'all afternoon carefully check the code but I can not find the error ... I always turn to you because maybe fatigue, often can 'distract me.

Thank you very much for all the help ....

```
#import "UFF_Chat.h"
#import "FF_CellChat.h"


@interface UFF_Chat ()

@end

@implementation UFF_Chat
@synthesize tfEntry;
@synthesize ChatData;
@synthesize chatTable;

BOOL _reloading;

#define TEXTFIELD_HEIGHT  70.0f
#define TOOLBAR_HEIGHT  40.0f
#define MAX_ENTRIES_LOADED 25

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tfEntry.delegate = self;
    tfEntry.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

    if (refresh == nil) {

        PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - chatTable.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, chatTable.bounds.size.height)];
        view.delegate = self;
        [chatTable addSubview:view];
        refresh = view;
    }
    //  update the last update date
    [refresh refreshLastUpdatedDate];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self freeKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource{

    //  should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload
    //  put here just for demo
    _reloading = YES;
    [self loadLocalChat];
    [chatTable reloadData];
}

- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData{

    //  model should call this when its done loading
    _reloading = NO;
    [refresh egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:chatTable];

}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated   {

    chatData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [self loadLocalChat];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"the text content%@",tfEntry.text);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (tfEntry.text.length>0) {
        // updating the table immediately
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text", @"userName", @"date", nil];
        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tfEntry.text, userName, [NSDate date], nil];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        [chatData addObject:dictionary];

        NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
        [chatTable beginUpdates];
        [chatTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [chatTable endUpdates];
        [chatTable reloadData];

        // going for the parsing
        PFObject *newMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Chat"];
        [newMessage setObject:tfEntry.text forKey:@"text"];
        [newMessage setObject:userName forKey:@"userName"];
        [newMessage setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
        [newMessage saveInBackground];
        tfEntry.text = @"";
    }

    // reload the data
    [self loadLocalChat];
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    [refresh egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    [refresh egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate Methods

- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

    [self reloadTableViewDataSource];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

}

- (BOOL)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceIsLoading:(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

    return _reloading; // should return if data source model is reloading

}

- (NSDate*)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated:(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

    return [NSDate date]; // should return date data source was last changed

}

-(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id) sender
{
    [self.tfEntry resignFirstResponder];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [chatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FF_CellChat *cell = (FF_CellChat *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"chatCellIdentifier"];
    NSUInteger row = [chatData count]-[indexPath row]-1;

    if (row < chatData.count){
        NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"text"];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
        cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(75, 14, size.width +20, size.height + 20);
        cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        cell.textString.text = chatText;
        [cell.textString sizeToFit];

        NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
        NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;

        cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:chatData.count-indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"text"];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(225.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

    return labelSize.height + 40;
}
-(void) registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) freeKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard was shown");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y- keyboardFrame.size.height+TOOLBAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard will hide");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardFrame.size.height-TOOLBAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"the text content%@",tfEntry.text);
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [tfEntry resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)loadLocalChat
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];

    if ([chatData count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
        [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
        NSLog(@"Trying to retrieve from cache");
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d chats from cache.", objects.count);
                [chatData removeAllObjects];
                [chatData addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                [chatTable reloadData];
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];

    __block int totalNumberOfEntries = 0;
    [query1 orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query1 countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The count request succeeded. Log the count
            NSLog(@"There are currently %d entries", number);
            totalNumberOfEntries = number;
            if (totalNumberOfEntries > [chatData count]) {
                NSLog(@"Retrieving data");
                int theLimit;
                if (totalNumberOfEntries-[chatData count]>MAX_ENTRIES_LOADED) {
                    theLimit = MAX_ENTRIES_LOADED;
                }
                else {
                    theLimit = totalNumberOfEntries-[chatData count];
                }
             //   query.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:theLimit];
                [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        // The find succeeded.
                        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d chats.", objects.count);
                        [chatData addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                        NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        for (int ind = 0; ind < objects.count; ind++) {
                            NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ind inSection:0];
                            [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
                        }
                        [chatTable beginUpdates];
                        [chatTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                        [chatTable endUpdates];
                        [chatTable reloadData];
                        [chatTable scrollsToTop];
                    } else {
                        // Log details of the failure
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    }
                }];
            }

        } else {
            // The request failed, we'll keep the chatData count?
            number = [chatData count];
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the contents of the NSDictionary in question?

Comment: I noticed that the problem 'that I have to save the username as the current user ! unfatti changing the user string works but does not save the current user pf do not understand why

Comment: Sorry, the problem you have stated is very unclear. You will need to  be more specific about your problem, and let us know what steps you have taken to debug the problem so far.

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote so badly: (Forgive my very bad English.
The tutorial showed how to make this chat a chat through the use of Parse.com. I followed step by step tutorials and chat userName provided that the object was saved through the use of a nickname from the user. But I need the object @ "userName" is the username with which you are registered to the app so the typical [PFUser currentUser];

Comment: I tried several tests but I can not find the right gaming and keep getting the error from the log:

- [NSDictionary initWithObjects: forKeys:]: count of objects (1) Differs from count of keys (3) '

This is a clear mistake having done all the various changes so I'm sure my error is about how to set the PFUser currentUser in my code. M file I posted here.
   Thanks, Rory

Comment: Try @"username" not @"userName"

Comment: We're almost there! : D In fact, the only rescue is perfectly ... Continue Error - [PFUser length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

when I edit @ "userName" in @ "username" the cell of TableView.
I wanted to edit the cell because I needed that person views the label containing the username.

The error occurs right here

  `cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"username"]`

Comment: Solved with:
'PFUser *fromUser = [PFUser currentUser];
        NSString *comment = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row],fromUser objectForKey:@"username" ];
        cell.userLabel.text = comment;  '   Thankssss Ahar!!